# Api data not being displayed due to CORS -axios. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, steam

I am making an api call to the steam review api with this link: "[api link](https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/1389990?json=1&language=english)"

I have used another link with my code and was able to get responses and even display the data on my screen, so I have no faulty code. I am currently using this to try and get the result content: `comment.reviews.review`

This is my complete code:

```js
function Home() {
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchComments();
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(comments);
  }, [comments]);
  const fetchComments = async () => {
    const response = await axios(
      "https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/1389990?json=1&language=english"
    );
    setComments(response.data);
  };
  var limitComments = comments.slice(0, 3);

  return (
    {limitComments &&
       limitComments.map((comment) => (
          <p>{comment.reviews.review}</p>
                        
     ))}
   );
}

export default Home;
```

What is wrong with request? I have tried using different keys like `comment.author.reviews.review`.

Comment: Doesn't the title answer the question in the description?

Answer (score -2):

You'll want to brush up on CORS since that's what's preventing your request from succeeding. Here's a great resource:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS